# How do I prevent Jenkins pipeline (workflow) from triggering multiple builds when used with multiple git repos?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, githooks, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

If you have a workflow which uses multiple git repositories, each git push triggers a build in Jenkins.

If I have a workflow job configured to poll 10 git repositories and I pushed changes to all of them [quite possible when doing a release build] - that's 10 builds in the queue. This is both good and bad.  Bad because we will have changes in different repositories and we would like to kick off the build once all the files are in. At the same time I don't want to avoid polling the repositories.

> stage 'REPO-1' {
>   git branch: "feature/testbranch", changelog: true,
>   poll: true, url: 'ssh://git@stash.com/repo1.git', credentialsId: 'xxx' 
>   }
>
> stage 'REPO-2' {
>   git branch: "feature/testbranch", changelog: true,
>   poll: true, url: 'ssh://git@stash.com/repo2.git', credentialsId: 'xxx'
>   }

Is there a way I can prevent this behavior perhaps introduce a delay in polling.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `Additional Behaviours: Polling ignores commits with certain messages`?

> If set, and Jenkins is set to poll for changes, Jenkins will ignore any revisions committed with message matched to Pattern when determining if a build needs to be triggered...

Steps:

1. Commit your changes with `IGNORE` message.
2. Once all repositories are up to date, then trigger build manually or with `no-IGNORE` message.

Checkout step:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
    extensions: [[$class: 'UserExclusion', excludedUsers: ''], 
    [$class: 'MessageExclusion', excludedMessage: '.*\\[ignore-this-commit\\].*']], 
    submoduleCfg: [], 
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/luxengine/math.git']]])
```

Comment: I have tried the quiet period option in Workflow and it worked pretty well

Comment: Tried this metod, build is still executed.

Comment: I seem to have this issue as well. anyone if this is been fixed?

Comment: I have tried excludedUsers, excludedMessage in Jenkins job and in Atlassian bitbucket webhook added Ignore User as well. But still the builds are triggering

Answer (score 0):

I have enabled **quiet period** option and added a timeout of 60 seconds. This will help Jenkins workflow to collapse changes to multiple repositories within a quiet period into one  and trigger single build instead of triggering multiple builds for  every SCM change.[image]

Keep in mind that the quiet period in my case is set to 60 seconds, as long as the other changes are within 60 seconds it will add another 60 seconds quiet period to watch for any other changes in the repositories. But If you make another change to the repository after 60 seconds it will be another build.

Comment: can you explain how to set quiet periods in Jenkinsfile? I'm having trouble enabling this within a multi-branch project

Comment: @FedericoBonelli I suppose quiet period is not available when using multi-branch project.